# How to integrate a pdf, $f_{XYZ}$ within a 3-D sphere?

Tags: probability, integration, spherical-coordinates

Say that I have $f_{XYZ} = C$ that is defined within a 3-D sphere and that it's constant. If I want to obtain $f_X$, I have to integrate over $Y$ and $Z$ dimensions. What is the easiest way to do this, and how do I determine the limits of integration?

For within a sphere, I know we have to satisfy
$$
X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 < R^2 
$$

with $R$ being radius of sphere.

So my attempt looks something like this:
$$
f_X(x) = \int_?^? \int_{-\sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - z^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - z^2}} f_{XYZ}dydz
$$

But I am confused what the limits should be for $Z$. Is it simply from $0$ to $R$, or does it depend on $x$?

Comment: To answer your question, yes the $z$ limits would involve $x$. But first you have two problems with your $y$ limits. Your upper bound is incorrect, and while your lower bound is fine in this particular case, it isn't the most general for an arbitrary pdf because it doesn't cover the whole sphere.

Comment: @NinadMunshi For the upper bound, I am missing a square root. Is that what you're referring to or is there something else wrong?

Comment: @NinadMunshi As for the lower bound, I believe it should be the negative of the upper bound.

Comment: No those take care of all of the problems. Good job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you interset the plane $\{X=x\}\cap\mathbb{R}^3$ with the ball $\{X^2+Y^2+Z^2 \leq R^2\}\cap\mathbb{R}^3$ for fixed $x\in[-R,R]$ and project onto the $yz-$plane you're looking at the disc $$\{Y^2+Z^2\leq R^2-x^2\}\cap\mathbb{R}^2$$ That being said,
$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}f_{XYZ}(x,y,z)dzdy$$ whenever $x\in[-R,R]$ and $f_X(x)=0$ otherwise. You can evaluate this integral by converting to polar coordinates: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}rf_{XYZ}(x,r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))drd\theta$$
Moreover, $C$ must equal $\frac{3}{4\pi R^3}$ to ensure $\int_{\{x^2+y^2+z^2\leq R^2\}}f_{XYZ}dV=1$.

Comment: I am not sure the bounds of integration are correct on your polar integral. Note if $f_{XYZ}$ is constant, the LHS $f_X(x)$ should depend on $x$ since the sphere has different $x$-thickness for different $x$, but your integral on the RHS comes out constant.

Comment: Really? I got $f_X(x)=\frac{3}{4R^3}(R^2-x^2)$ for $x\in [-R,R]$ and $f_X(x)=0$ elsewhere, which is a density.

Comment: sorry, missed the limits -- my bad

Comment: In polar coordinates, where did you obtain the upper limit of $\sqrt{R^2 - x^2} for the variable $r$?

Comment: I know it's been a while since you thought anything about Calculus III, but do you remember how to convert a disc of radius $a$ centered about $(0,0)$ to polar coordinates? In other words, can you describe the region $\{(y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^2|y^2+z^2\leq a^2\}$ in polar form? That's all I did, and I took $a$ to be $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ while keeping in mind that $R$ and $x$ are fixed real numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I know that $y = a\cos(\theta), z = a\sin (\theta)$ (you could also swap y and z).

Comment: I think what I'm confused about in this case is what does the 2D disk have to do with the 3D  sphere?

Comment: Remember, we first intersected the ball $X^2+Y^2+Z^2 \leq R^2$ with the vertical plane $X=x$. This intersection is a disc of radius $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ centered about $(x,0,0)$, and then we projected this disc onto the $yz-$plane. This gave us a disc of radius $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ centered about the origin in the $yz-$plane, which you can represent in polar coordinates as the collection of all points $(r,\theta)$ such that $0\leq r\leq\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi.$

Comment: Ahh I can visualize the disk now. Is there a typo/duplicate in your comment about the disc?

Comment: lol yes I am experiencing some technical difficulties

Comment: Is it correct to say that you're just integrating over the circles on the y-z plane for a fixed $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to see that when you solve your result for $z$, you get
$$
z = \pm \sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2},
$$
which will be the bounds on the inner integral. Now when you collapse the sphere to the $xy$-plane, you end up with $x^2+y^2 < R^2$ and so $y = \pm \sqrt{R^2-x^2}$, so you have
$$
f_X(x)
 = \int_{y=-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{y=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}
      \left[ \int_{z=-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}}^{z=\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}} f_{XYZ}(x,y,z) dz \right] dy
$$

**UPDATE**

To integrate, since $f_{XYZ} \equiv C$ is constant, the inner integral is just $2C\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$ and you can use a trig substitution or a standard tabled integral, say #30 in [this list](http://integral-table.com/)

Comment: I took calc 3 10 years ago, and recall struggling with spherical coordinates and had a hard time finding correct limits of integration. Is there a good way to visualize these limits? Also another question I have is, in cartesian frame, it seems these integrals are difficult to evaluate. Is there a simple approach to evaluating them?

Comment: @dd22205 To visualize, imagine a sphere in 3D, the equation of the left halfsphere (in the $x>0$ octant is $x=\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2}$ and in the $x<0$ octant is the negative of that. Essentially, you are differentiating between 2 half-spheres, and then in the 2D projection, between two semi-circles.

Comment: When you're in the 2-D space, does the circle you're looking at have radius $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$?

Comment: @dd22205 no. Projecting the entire sphere of radius $R$ into $xy$-plane, you end up with a circle of radius $R$...

Comment: But isn't $R^2 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ on the x-z plane?